# SDK Manager : Error in opening

Tags: android, android-studio

8:55:23 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '"F:\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\find_java64.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2015-08-04 18:55:23 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.

I am getting the error when i click on the SDK Manager button in eclipse for android

Comment: moved to android studio